# Text converter with javascript split()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bulk data in written text like this:

```
useremail1@gmail.com:token1 | Time = US | Alfabet = abc | EndToken = July 22, 2022 | Generate Since = July 2021 
useremail2@yahoo.com:token2 | Time = US | Alfabet = bcd | EndToken = July 11, 2022 | Generate Since = June 2021
useremail3@yahoo.com:token3 | Time = UK | Alfabet = dca | EndToken = July 11, 2022 | Generate Since = June 2020
```

How to make a tool with javascript by inserting bulk data into a text area then the result is in a modal popup with text result like this:

Convert Result/expected output:

```
+No.1
Email: useremail1@gmail.com
Token: token1
Time = US
Alfabet = abc
EndToken = July 22, 2022
Generate Since = July 2021
 
+No.2
Email: useremail2@yahoo.com
Token: token2
Time = US
Alfabet = bcd
EndToken = July 11, 2022
Generate Since = June 2021

+No.3
Email: useremail3@yahoo.com
Token: token3
Time = UK
Alfabet = dca
EndToken = July 11, 2022
Generate Since = June 2020
```

I made the input textarea look like this:

```js
function convert() {
    document.getElementById("convertResult").value = "+No.1\nEmail: useremail1@gmail.com\nToken: token1\nTime = US\nAlfabet = abc\nEndToken = July 22, 2022\nGenerate Since = July 2021\n\n+No.2\nEmail: useremail2@yahoo.com\nToken: token2\nTime = US\nAlfabet = bcd\nEndToken = July 11, 2022\nGenerate Since = June 2021\n\n+No.3\nEmail: useremail3@yahoo.com\nToken: token3\nTime = UK\nAlfabet = dca\nEndToken = July 11, 2022\nGenerate Since = June 2020\n\n";
}

  let buttonCopy = document.getElementById("copyResult"),
      input = document.getElementById("convertResult");

  buttonCopy.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    input.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Result copied");
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  
  <form class="m-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Paste bulk text data bellow</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="8">
      useremail1@gmail.com:token1 | Time = US | Alfabet = abc | EndToken = July 22, 2022 | Generate Since = July 2021
      useremail2@yahoo.com:token2 | Time = US | Alfabet = bcd | EndToken = July 11, 2022 | Generate Since = June 2021
      useremail3@yahoo.com:token3 | Time = UK | Alfabet = dca | EndToken = July 11, 2022 | Generate Since = June 2020
      </textarea>
  </div>

  <button type="button" onclick="convert()" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Convert
</button>
</form>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Convert Result</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea id="convertResult" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="8"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="copyResult" class="btn btn-primary">Copy Result</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The value entered will be like the code sample above, and the expected result will be like the code in the "Convert Result:" section.

Comment: Research the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method. You just need to do it twice to get the output you need, once on a line break, then again on the pipe within each string of that resulting array. If you are having issues implementing this please edit your question to show what you've tried so that we can help you debug it

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am a newbie in this, can you give an example?

Comment: Did you read the `split()` documentation that Rory linked you to? Have you made any effort at all to solve the problem yourself? Where did you get stuck, what help do you need: what *is* the problem?

Comment: Which part *exactly* are you stuck on?  You know how to set an input value, so should know how to read the value.  Are you stuck on how to `split()` the value by newlines?  How to loop through the resulting array?  How to index an array element directly?   How to concatenate a string?

Comment: Hi @David Thomas, I have read the documentation provided, but I don't understand how to call the value entered in the input textarea and produce the output as expected.

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m, everything you mentioned i got stuck there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will do that:

```
let $btn = document.querySelector('#convert')
$btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let inputArr = document.querySelector('#exampleFormControlTextarea1').value.split('\n');
    let $result = document.querySelector('#exampleFormControlTextarea2')
    let number = 1    
    let final = []

    for (row of inputArr) {
        let rowArr = row.split(' | ')
        let first = rowArr.shift().split(':')
        let nrString = `+No.` + number
        let mail = `Email: ${first[0]}`
        let token = `Token: ${first[1]}`

        rowArr.unshift(nrString, mail, token);
        rowArr = rowArr.join('\n')
        final.push(rowArr)
        number++
    }

    let finalText = final.join('\n\n')
    $result.value = finalText
})
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/qg2Lez0b/1/

You have to rename the second textarea to `#exampleFormControlTextarea2` and give a id to the button `convert`.

Comment: Hi Tim, Absolutely perfect, Thank you so much. You really saved my time.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is as follows, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// defining a named function to handle the formatting/conversion of the entered data,
// using Arrow function syntax and passing in the Event Object ('e') from the (later)
// use of EventTarget.addEventListener():
const convertFormat = (e) => {
    // caching the element into which the source data is entered:
    const source = document.querySelector('#exampleFormControlTextarea1'),
      // retrieving that entered data, and using String.prototype.trim() to
      // remove the leading and trailing white-space:
      sourceData = source.value.trim(),
      // splitting the sourceData into an array of individual entries/records,
      // using String.prototype.split() with a regular expression literal, to
      // split the string on a character-sequence of a word-boundary (\b) at the
      // end of each line ($); this uses the 'm' and 'g' flags; 'g' (global) to
      // match all occurrences and 'm' (multiline) to treat '$' as the end-of-line
      // character, rather than end-of-string.
      // Once this array is created we pass it to Array.prototype.map(), again
      // using an Arrow function, to call String.prototype.trim() on every array-element
      // of the created Array:
      records = sourceData.split(/\b$/gm).map((v) => v.trim());

    // if we have a truthy records result:
    if (records) {
      // we create a variable 'res' by iterating over the records Array with Array.prototype.map()
      // to create a new Array based on the inital Array:
      let res = records.map(
        // here we pass in a reference to the current Array-element ('arr') and the index of the
        // current Array-element ('i'):
        (arr, i) => {
          // using destructuring assignment to create a variable called 'mail' and another that
          // takes all remaining entries from the Array called 'keyValues'; to assign these variables
          // we split the current Array-element ('arr') on a character sequence of one-or-more 
          // white-space characters (\s+) followed by a '|' character (escaped with a back-slash
          // because it's a special character in regular expressions) and followed by more white-
          // space characters:
          let [mail, ...keyValues] = arr.split(/\s+\|\s+/),
              // we then use more destructuring assignments; here we split the 'useremail@gmail.com:token1'
              // String at the ':' character, the first entry of the created array will be assigned to the
              // 'email' variable, and the String that followed the ':' character will be assigned to the
              // 'token' variable:
              [email, token] = mail.split(':'),
            // here we create a template-literal string, as that allows us to interpolate JavaScript
            // variables and line-breaks into the String:
            // so first we have a line-break, and create a String of '+' with the interpolated value of
            // i (the Array-element's index) plus 1 (the index is zero-based, and you seem to want a
            // 1-based count), followed by another line-break and the 'Email:' String followed by
            // another interpolated variable:
            resultString = `
+${i+1},
Email: ${email}
Token: ${token}`;

          // here we iterate over the keyValues array, with an Arrow function passing in a reference
          // to the current Array-element ('kv'):
          keyValues.forEach(
            (kv) => {
              // in this anonymous function, we split the kv array-element String on the '=' character,
              // and then trim the resulting Array entries; those entries are then passed to the variables
              // 'key' and 'val':
              let [key, val] = kv.split('=').map((v) => v.trim());
              // we then append these details to the resultString, again using a template-literal:
              resultString += `
${key}: ${val}`;
            });
          // we return the resultString:
          return resultString;
        // and we join all the Array elements together - using Array.prototype.join() - with a line-break
        // using a template-literal:
        }).join(`
        `);
      // we retrieve the '#output' element, and update its value:
      document.querySelector('#output').value = res;
    }
  },
  // we find the first/only <button> element on the page (adjust the selector to suit your use-case):
  convertButton = document.querySelector('button');

// And here we use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the convertFormat() function (note the lack
// of parentheses) as the event-handler for the 'click' event on the <button>:
convertButton.addEventListener('click', convertFormat);
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5em;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding-block: 0.25em;
  padding-inline: 0.5em;
  width: clamp(10rem, 60vw, 1000px);
}

textarea {
  min-height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Paste bulk text data below</label>
  <textarea id="exampleFormControlTextarea1">
  useremail1@gmail.com:token1 | Time = US | Alfabet = abc | EndToken = July 22, 2022 | Generate Since = July 2021
  useremail2@yahoo.com:token2 | Time = US | Alfabet = bcd | EndToken = July 11, 2022 | Generate Since = June 2021
  useremail3@yahoo.com:token3 | Time = UK | Alfabet = dca | EndToken = July 11, 2022 | Generate Since = June 2020
</textarea>
  <button>Convert</button>
  <textarea id="output"></textarea>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eybd1czv/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for being willing to explain in great detail, and by the way I like the simple look you make. Once again, thank you.